# htacces, redirect some sub-folder to another one

Tags: html, .htaccess

I need to redirect a sub-folder to another sub-folder.

My problem is that I want to redirect all the links like

```
http://example.org/make/satellite/*  or http://example.org/space/satellite/*
```

to

```
  http://example.org/satellite/*
```

but it does't work. I am using this code

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.org [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ example.org$1 [L,R=301]
RedirectMatch 301 ^/satellite/(.*)$ http://example.org/satellite/$1
```

How can I do this with the htacces file?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to look for two matches and ignore the first one:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/(.*)/satellite/(.*)$  http://example.org/satellite/$2
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your Root/.htaccess file :

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/make/satellite/(.*)$  http://example.org/satellite/$1 
RedirectMatch 301 ^/space/satellite/(.*)$  http://example.org/satellite/$1
```

This redirects http://example.com/make/satellite/ or http://example.com/space/satellite/ to http://example.com/satellite .

Comment: That will work if those are the two only possible cases. Otherwise, you will have to add a rule for every different directory.